# Continuously Pull Data from Backend Database?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am new to Android development and Java, so bear with me, and please let me know if any of my phrasing or anything is wrong. I've searched for many hours, and I've come across so many unknown terms and methods of implementation that may or may not work that I've gone and thrown myself into a tizzy.

I'm currently developing a type of feed for an Android app, and my main goal is that I want to be able to pull down on the feed (similar to the Gmail app) and have newly-entered data in the database loaded onto the device and displayed on the screen. Just to be clear, I only want to pull data when the app is opened.

Here's some background on the app. The main activity hosts an inner `FragmentPagerAdapter` class which controls 3 fragments in a `TabLayout`. The first tab is the feed, the second is the list of contacts (which I also want to update in a manner similar to the feed), and the third is just profile stuff.

What I've done so far is that I have a seeded db on a backend server (Python/SqlAlchemy), and I've set up an `AsyncTask` in both the feed and contacts fragments that GETs (using `HttpURLConnection`) all the appropriate data and brings it client-side. From there I extract the data I need from the received JSON, and display it in dynamically generated `TextViews`. This part all works great.

I've tried stopping/restarting the `AsyncTask`, but the docs say that's a no-go. I've tried the `notifyDataSetChange()`, but it's also not working. Also, just to confirm, does `notifyDataSetChange()` automatically update the fragments in a way that accomplishes my goal? I've read some of the documentation about it and looked at many topics here, but I couldn't put together a clear answer for my implementation and I'm really confused about it...

So can someone can direct me in where to learn how to continuously pull data from a backend database after the `AsyncTask` has already been run or is currently running? Or at least how to phrase it so I can search more efficiently? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AsyncTask` is the way to go. In your `onResume( )`, execute the `AsyncTask`. Yes, docs do say that it is a no-go to reuse the `AsyncTask`. So you will need to do this:

```
new MyAsyncTask.execute( url );
```

Now that was for a one-shot update. How about periodic updates? The simplest way would be to use a `CountDownTimer` that periodically fires an `AsyncTask`. Docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Also, don't make an anonymous `CountDownTimer`, instead, make a class that extends it. So, you would have a class named `MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer`.  The `onFinish( )` is where you would fire your `AsyncTask`.

Hope that helps

Comment: From what I understand, the fragment's `onResume()` will only be called if the activity that hosts the fragment is paused and then resumed, so I'm not sure that will allow users to pull down on the feed (which is itself a fragment) and have updated data from the server be fetched. But I'll keep that timer suggestion in my back pocket for now, thanks for that!

Comment: It turns out that all I was looking for was Swipe-to-Refresh (https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html).